# Surjection, Recursion and Induction

Tags: induction, recursion

Let $S$ be the set inductively defined by:

1) $* \in S$

2) If $a \in S$ and $b \in S$ then $\langle a,b \rangle \in S$.

For each natural number $n \in \mathbf{N}$, let $d(n)=\text{max}\{k \quad|\quad5^{k} \quad \text{divides} \quad n\}$ and $e(n)=\text{max}\{k \quad | \quad 2^{k} \quad \text{divides} \quad n\}$. Let $f:\mathbf{N} \to S$ be defined recursively by:

$$f(0)=*$$ $$f(n)=\langle f(d(n)),f(e(n))\rangle$$

Show that $f$ is surjective.

Answer (score 3):

- $f(0)=\star$ is in $\operatorname{im}f$.
- If $a=f(n), b=f(m)$ are in $\operatorname{im}f$, then $\langle a,b\rangle = f(2^m5^n)$ is in $\operatorname{im}f$.

Comment: Is that really everything one has to do?

Comment: I still remain confused as to how the assumption of $a=f(n), b=f(m) \in S$ can be turned into showing that $\langle a, b \rangle=f(2^{m}5^{n})$. How is this done?

Comment: $d(2^m5^n) = n, e(2^m5^n) = m$, so $f(2^m5^n) = \langle f(n),f(m) \rangle = \langle a,b \rangle$